# User variable for a db name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to declare a variable for the database name which would be used across a large SELECT query with JOINs from various tables. I would later like to reproduce the same query to run on another DB with the same structure. I would like to automatically change the source database name when I change the declared variable value ("@db").

I tried this:

```
SET @db := 'database_1'
SELECT * FROM @db.table_1
```

However, this results in a syntax error. Is there any way of doing something like this?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: you can't do it in any dbms ,  unless you use `dynamic sql`

Comment: The need for this type of evaluated query usually indicates a non-standard database design... best practice design guidance for relational databases specifically restricts the dynamic evaluation of database/entity names. You could use *dynamic SQL* to achieve this, but it's generally not such a great idea if you don't know *exactly* what you're doing, as you can introduce security holes quite easily this way. Curious - what requirement gives rise to this sort of design where you have disparate databases with (ostensibly) the same table/relation structure...?